# Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout: layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

when i run the following layout i get a compiler warning in eclipse that says:

Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout: layout_weight

Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: As Barak suggests, wrap your 2 `ListView`s in a vertical `LinearLayout`. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the layout_weight callout from your listviews (or wrap them in a linearlayout).

As it's telling you, it's not valid when the immediate parent layout is a framelayout.

Answer (score 4):

This is a direct quote from the Android docs - [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

Try using `android:layout_gravity` instead of `android:layout_weight`.